# What's your favorite way of testing javascript code snippets?

Tags: javascript, debugging, testing

What's your favorite way of testing javascript code snippets?

I like to use the browser's address field directly:

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById("textbox").style.display='none'))
javascript:void(document.write("Testing"))
javascript:alert(parseFloat("33.33"))
```

If using the latter trick, don't forget to wrap everything in a `void()` call or an `alert()` call, lest the page will be blanked out.

Alternatively, there is the Firebug extension on firefox in which you can edit javascript code arbitrarily.

Any other interesting ways out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Firebug Console Logging](http://getfirebug.com/console.html)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) to test snippets of code with snippets of html and some js frameworks.

Comment: Great tool! Never saw this before.

Answer (score 4):

JSFiddle is quick, easy, and social! 
http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3):

I use Firebug for pretty much everything JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) by far the most times.
Otherwise I use the addressbar, or simply adding a button or link on the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug and run Javascript on the fly on IE, you can alos give [Debugbar](http://www.debugbar.com/) a try. It works great.

Comment: I'll have to try this one out; I've been hurting for a Firebug-equivalent for IE. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use the tryit.asp on [link text](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input)  on w3school as I normally check my html with that site anyway. It also allows me to try variations before I go to far.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test small scripts across different browsers, I have a html file lying around which just contains

```
<pre><script>
</script></pre>
```

Logging gets done via `document.writeln()`.

Answer (score 0):

I like [JavaScript eval console](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/entry-JavaScriptevalconsole.aspx).

The author of the tool has provided the code as well, so you can also it use it locally.